# Click events inside jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'd like to do something relatively simple with a jQuery plugin. I'm just not totally sure about a click event inside of it.

Here's a simple example that works...

```
$.fn.testy = function() {
  var testElem = this.find('p');
    testElem.click(function(){
      testElem.addClass('highlighted');
      ^^^^^^^^
   });

};

$("div").testy();
```

Now, if instead of writing `testElem.addClass('highlighted');`, I put `this.addClass('highlighted');`, I would get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLParagraphElement> has no method 'addClass'`

I understand that `this` refers to jQuery in this context. I'm making it work by just reusing the variable, but that feels wrong. How do I target the thing that I'm clicking?

For example, if I were just writing a script, I'd write something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

How could I do that while targeting only the `a` elements inside the specified element?

Comment: So you want to add class to the div right?

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/zzWEb/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me explain it in comments:

```
$.fn.testy = function() {
  // `this` here refers to all `DIV`s as jQuery objects

  var testElem = this.find('p');
  // `testElem` is now collection of all `P`s from all `DIV`s, as jQuery object

  testElem.click(function(){ // <<--
      // Note you are now inside another function
      // This function gets called for each `P`

      // of course you don't want to apply yo all `testElem`, only clicked one
      // `this` inside the new function is the `P` AS DOM Element not jQuery
      var $testP = $(this); // just wrapping one `P` in jQuery object
      // Now you can
      $testP.addClass('highlighted');
      // You didn't need the variable, but for explanation
   }); // <<-- finished click function

   // back to plugin function    
};
```

Here's an even better example that follows jQuery plugin best practices (allowing chaining by returning `each()` for the jQuery objects called for your plugin):

http://jsfiddle.net/Meligy/s2wN4/

Comment: This is a fantastic response. You made it much clearer than the official jQuery documentation.They kind of glossed over how `return this.each()` works in the plugin context, but your jsFiddle was perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clever explanation. It helped me to transform a common function into a plugin. Thanks a lot @Meligy

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$(this).addClass('highlighted');
```

Comment: That results in this error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLParagraphElement> has no method 'css' `